# iPad screen size return wrong value

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, storyboard

I am making app that runs in all iPhone device 4s,5,5s,6,6+ and iPads..

In this if we choose iPhone 4s simulator it will load 4s storyboard.
I have designed separate storyboards for different size of screen.

It works good in all iPhone device but when i choose iPad in simulator option it gives me iPhone 4s screen.

This is code which load different storyboards as per screen size in AppDelegate.

```
- (UIStoryboard *)grabStoryboard

{
// determine screen size
int screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
NSLog(@"screenHeight:-%d",screenHeight);///here it it gives me 480 in iPad so it goes in case 480.
UIStoryboard *storyboard;


switch (screenHeight)
{
        // iPhone 4s
    case 480:
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-4s" bundle:nil];
        break;

        // iPhone 5s
    case 568:
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-5s" bundle:nil];
        break;

        // iPhone 6
    case 667:
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-6" bundle:nil];
        break;

        // iPhone 6 Plus
    case 736:
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-6Plus" bundle:nil];
        break;

    default:
        // it's an iPad
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        break;
}
 return storyboard;
}
```

And called this method in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

This code is working great in my other app.

Comment: The way you are doing it for multiple devices is completely wrong. Consider the Unified Storyboard approach..

Comment: so what should i do and this runs good in my other app

Comment: Use Size Classes for different device configuration and this will lead to less code and build size.

Comment: can u give me more detail or link for that

Comment: Since it is too broad to put it here. You can go for a better tutorial of "Size Classes" and Google is really a good search engine.

Comment: ok thanks for your time

Comment: Also, is your app universal or iPhone only? iPhone only apps will open at iPhone 4 resolution on an ipad

Comment: yeaahhh... thanks paulw..i forgot to check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is zoomed in your iPad to the resolution of iPhone 4. You need to set the target Devices to Universal.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to configure a separate storyboard for each resolution. In Xcode, you can configure layouts for different screen sizes via Interface Builder. At the bottom, you can alter constraints for the various screen sizes.

[image]

[Here's a brief tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5wD8dvSDbM) that should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: got answer by paulw in comment